# How to get a window title and scan it every 100ms use python?

Tags: python, win32gui

with python, I want to get a window title,a stock software window.

the window's title will change when I browse another stock ,now I want to  scan it every 100ms and return the new title,but the front text in the window title is the same text.

I can print the title in cmd,but I don't know how to scan it every 100ms and return

I use this code:

```
from win32gui import *
import re

titles = set() 
titlekey = ''

def foo(hwnd,nouse):
    if IsWindow(hwnd) and IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) and IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        titles.add(GetWindowText(hwnd))

EnumWindows(foo, 0) 
lt = [t for t in titles if t] 
lt.sort() 
for t in lt:
    if re.match(titlekey,t):
        print t
```

How to scan every 100ms and return the new title when it change?

Comment: Where you have code, indent it to format as code, don't put it in a blockquote. Edited for you.

Comment: No worries, you know now for next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put it in a loop:

```
import win32gui
tempWindowName=win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
import time
while True:
    if (tempWindowName==win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()))
        pass
    else
        tempWindowName=win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
        #do what you want
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: em.....I think my idea maybe wrong.I want get the title when it change,return the new title,and use some text in the title to Query data in sqlite,now I think scan it every 100ms maybe can't work.so......I have no idea.....

Comment: 1. i think this answers your question. 2. what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: sure，your answer resover my question。but may be my idea is wrong。my program need
to get the active window's title or it's parent window's title,and return new title when the title change,if no change then do nothing,how sould I do?use hook?

Comment: 1. edit your question to ask what you want to ask. 2. except the answer. 3. if you need more assistance, ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much,I have edited your new code ,and put it in my program,it work.:)